Why is time_machine returning a wrong date?
The time_machine module in python keeps setting a time that is one day earlier than the date that I set.
I must be missing something obvious!
Here's an example of a simple program showing the discrepancy:
import time_machine
import datetime as dt

def main():
    print(timemachine())
    print(today_time())

def timemachine():
    with time_machine.travel(dt.datetime(2024, 7, 24), tick = False):
        return dt.date.today().isoformat()
def today_time():
    return dt.datetime.today()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Output:
2024-07-23 -> That's the output for dt.datetime(2024, 7, 24), which is a day earlier.
2024-07-25 11:38:30.354514 -> That's the output for today's date, to ensure that there's nothing wrong with datetime.

What time zone are you in?

i am in Eastern Standard Time, UTC -5

make sure to set correct time zones, for both the time-machine module as well as datetime.today. They show the first on their landing page on pypi: https://pypi.org/project/time-machine/
